# Spring Boot java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I get A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction() error when trying to call the DELETE api. Not sure, if I am missing any JPA related configurations.

## Questionnarie.java #

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questionnaries")
public class Questionnarie {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_seq", sequenceName="questionnaries_id_seq")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;


@Column(name = "personname")
@NotNull
private String personname;


@Column(name = "question")
@NotNull
private String question;

@Column(name = "response")
@NotNull
private String response;

public Questionnarie() {}

public Questionnarie(@NotNull String personname, @NotNull String question, @NotNull String response) {
    super();
    this.personname = personname;
    this.question = question;
    this.response = response;
}
/* Not including GETTERS AND SETTERS for brevity */
```

## QuestionnarieController.java #

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/questionnaries/{id}")
    public void deleteQuestionnarie(@PathVariable Long id){

            questionnarieService.deleteQuestionnarie(id);
    }
```

## QuestionnarieService.java

```
public void deleteQuestionnarie(Long id) {
        questionnarieRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
```

## QuestionnarieRepository.java #

```
public void deleteById(Long id);
```

## application.properties

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/testDS

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, since you want to delete a **Questionnarie**, and for that `RequestMapping` you're using only an **id** as parameter. Before deleting, you need to load a **Questionnarie** to delete it.

Something like:

```
public void deleteQuestionnarie(Long id) {
     Questionnarie questionnaire = questionnarieRepository.find(id);
     questionnarieRepository.delete(questionnaire);
}
```